# Ensure buttons visible

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to scroll buttons into view in two different scenarios.

One scenario is upon clicking a list item, and the second scenario is when a text field is focused.[Gif showing both scenarios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtba7.gif)

From the example, I would like the "edit" and "delete" buttons to scroll into view when the list item is clicked. And I would like the "Save" and "Cancel" buttons to scroll into view when the text field is focused.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you have already tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your buttons with `Visibility` widgets, and use bool variables to set when they should be visible.